# Incompatible types error on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, incompatibletypeerror

I can't understand what the issue is. I did the exact same thing previously using a list view where I had to pass results from the Parse database to a list view adapter and it worked perfectly.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
         adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(GalleryViewTest.this, worldpopulationlist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

The following line of code is what results in the error.

> adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(GalleryViewTest.this, worldpopulationlist);

Hovering over the error produces the following message:

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
> Found:com.example.gallerypaseupload.galleryview.ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: What does `com.example.gallerypaseupload.galleryview.ViewPagerAdapter` inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(GalleryViewTest.this, worldpopulationlist);
```

to

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

And your View Pager Adapter Look Like This

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int pagerCount = 3;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

//Return the fragments
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {

        case 0:
            return Frag1.create(i);

        case 1:
            return Frag2.create(i);
        case 2:
            return Frag3.create(i);



        default:
            return Frag1.create(i);
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagerCount;
}
}
```

And fragment follows

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment{

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";



public Frag1 () {
}

public static Frag1 create(int pageNumber) {
    Frag1 fragment = new Frag1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout .
    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    initComponents();
    return rootView;
}}
```

**This is related to view pager transition using fragments.same way you can do the needful.**

**View Pager Image Slider** : http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/

Comment: The issue arises when i'm trying to add the the information from the parse database into the view. It works fine when I manually add the information using an array. I appreciate the attempt @Anoop M.